# css transition animation doesn't work for decreasing size of image

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions

CSS Transition for increasing size of image works, but doesn't work for decreasing. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
 $scope.myImgClass = 'start-class';
});
app.animation('.fadeOut', function(){
 return {
  enter: function(element, parentElement, afterElement, doneCallback){},
  leave: function(element, doneCallback){},
  move: function(element, parentElement, afterElement, doneCallback){},
  addClass: function(element, className, done){
   jQuery(element).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000);
  },
  removeClass: function(element, className, done){
   jQuery(element).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
  }
 };
});
```

```css
.shrink-add, .shrink-remove{
  -webkit-transition:all ease 2.5s;
  -moz-transition:all ease 2.5s;
  -o-transition:all ease 2.5s;
  transition:all ease 2.5s;
}
.shrink,
.shrink-add.shrink-add-active{
  height: 100px;
}

.start-class,
.shrink-remove.shrink-remove-active{
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>AngularJS $animate Service</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
  <h3>Image Animation</h3>
  <input type="button" ng-click="myImgClass='shrink'" value="Small"/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="myImgClass=''" value="Big"/>
  <hr>
  <img ng-class="myImgClass" src="http://vriz.net/vriz/nma/ch25/static/images/arch.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You code doesn't seem to be working, but based on this my best hunch is that you should try adding the transition to the actual image as opposed to the classes that are added to the image on the trigger of the button clicks.

Answer (score 1):

You code is not working, plus your codes examples are CSS & HTML is confusing.

Yet I am going to answer, cause as far as I understand this seems like one of the most basic mistake people make with the hovers :) Same is pointed by the @DawnPatrol in his comment!

When you want to apply transition, that transition belongs to the element so it is a behaviour of the element which determines how to perform the actual transition. Thus it should be applied to element no to any particular state!

**Wrong Method:**

```
<div class="box"></div>


.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.box:hover{
  transform: scale(2);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s; 
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s; 
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ; 
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Here transition is applicable to the hover state, so till the mouse it over the div transition will take place as expected but as soon as it leave it'll wont work & become jerky. Same happens when you apply transiton code to additional classes such as 'active', 'disabled'

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/a6a9d0e6/

**Right Method:**

```
<div class="box"></div>


.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s; 
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s; 
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ; 
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.box:hover{
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

Here hover will work as expected no matter what classes are added & what state the element is in, cause the transition is not specific to a particular state or class.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/a6a9d0e6/1/

Comment: Did you answer with considering AngularJS animate service?